# Assembling with TASM my program produces: Unexpected end of file encounter

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

```
                    .MODEL  TINY

Kod             SEGMENT

                ORG   100h/256
                ASSUME CS:Kod, DS:Tekst, SS:Stosik

Start:
                jmp     Petla

Tekst           DD      napis, '$'

Poczatek:
                mov     bl, napis

Petla:
                cmp     ah, '$'
                mov     al, [bx]
                jne     Wyswietlenie
                inc     bh
                mov     [bx], ax
                cmp     al, '$'
                mov     [bx - 1], ax
                je      Wyswietlenie
                mov     [bx], bl
                dec     bl
                jmp     Petla

Wyswietlenie:
                mov     ah, 09h
                mov     dx, OFFSET Tekst
                int     21h



                mov     ax, 4C70h
                int     21h

                ENDPRG  Poczatek

                KOD         ENDS
```

the error in the DOS is "**Fatal** program.asm(56) Unexpected end of file encounter".
The program should change letters in the word. Any suggests what can I do? I don't know what to edit to make it even lunch in DOS to check it step by step in the debugger.

Comment: What is the command you use to assemble the source into an executable program?

Comment: tasm program.asm /zi. the error appears in this moment

Comment: Don't you need some kind of `BEGIN` to match the `ENDPRG  Poczatek`?  The `Poczatek:` just sets a label there, and probably doesn't count.  But the error is that it reached the end of the file without finding something it was looking for, not an unmatched end or something, so maybe that's not it.

Comment: If you remove lines (in a copy of the file) until it assembles, maybe you can figure out which line TASM doesn't like.

Comment: My "Poczatek" is "Begin", I just wrote it as "Poczatek".

Comment: What is `ENDPRG`? It doesn't seem to be a tasm directive. And what's `napis`?

Comment: lol, I used to call my stack stosik too ;) back in the 90s :)

Comment: Szejku, where are the letters that are going to be changed? The only variable is `napis` but it doesn't contain any letter.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the original code you were given to fix is,and what the program is suppose to do I can tell you how to fix the issues that will allow you to at least compile and link this as a DOS COM program. I know that this assignment has a header (comments) that you have removed so I don't know what the program is suppose to do. If you provided the original assignment (including the header) in an update your question I might be able to help you further.

As it stands, with a DOS COM program you don't create `SEGMENTS` like a DOS EXE. So you have to remove the `kod SEGMENT`, `ASSUME CS:Kod, DS:Tekst, SS:Stosik`, `KOD ENDS`. You will have to place a `.code` directive after `.model TINY` and set the origin point with `org 100h`. A COM program needs an entry point. The entry point is `Start`. You need to end a COM program with an `END` statement that has the name of entry point in it. So the end of your file needs `END Start`.

The line `Tekst DD napis, '$'` needs to be `Tekst DB "napis", '$'`. Strings are created with `DB` (byte) directive and the string needs to be enclosed in quotes. The line `mov bl, napis` needs to move the offset (address) of `Tekst` to BX, not `napis`, so it should be `mov bx, offset Tekst`

The code to get you started so that you can at least assemble and link can look like this:

```
                .MODEL  TINY
                .code
                ORG   100h

Start:
                jmp     Poczatek

Tekst           DB      "napis", '$'

Poczatek:
                mov     bx, offset Tekst

Petla:
                cmp     ah, '$'
                mov     al, [bx]
                jne     Wyswietlenie
                inc     bh
                mov     [bx], ax
                cmp     al, '$'
                mov     [bx - 1], ax
                je      Wyswietlenie
                mov     [bx], bl
                dec     bl
                jmp     Petla

Wyswietlenie:
                mov     ah, 09h
                mov     dx, OFFSET Tekst
                int     21h



                mov     ax, 4C70h
                int     21h

                END Start
```

You should be able to use the turbo debugger to run and test the program and fix the logical errors that I can't help you with given the information provided.

---

I suspect from the code that the intent is to swap each pair of characters until the end of string is found. If that is the case then the main part of the code would probably be this:

```
Start:
                jmp     Poczatek

Tekst           DB      "napis", '$'

Poczatek:
                mov     bx, offset Tekst

Petla:
                mov     ah, [bx]
                cmp     ah, '$'
                je      Wyswietlenie
                inc     bx
                mov     al, [bx]
                cmp     al, '$'
                je      Wyswietlenie
                mov     [bx - 1], al
                mov     [bx], ah
                inc     bx
                jmp     Petla
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you have used

### START:

;then you have to end it also and to end it please write

### END START

; at the end of code

Further, the assembler NEEDS END directive as the END OF FILE command.
So, as we saw that **"END START**" is to be included in the code. But where?

The answer is that assembler always looks for **END** directive for END OF FILE command. 
So, include **END START** as the last line of code.

Note: FATAL ERROR ,UNEXPECTED END OF FILE
error will be solved by this, but I have not debugged other possible errors if there

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Comment: @Agilanbu Thank you for the suggestion. Anything else.